# Formatting a really long equation

Tags: equations, formatting, breqn, fit

I have a rather long set equations that span for about more than a page. I am trying to format it in a way that makes them [look like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376849/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-root-is-positive-real-for-this-polynomial),

Now, I tried using the `dmath*` command from the `breqn` library but to no avail, the respective output, though a little better, goes out of the page for some reason. It looks like this,
[image]

See the half of the equation getting cut. This isn't the case here on SE sites surprisingly. Is there any way I can format the equation in the manner [it is being done here on SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376849/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-root-is-positive-real-for-this-polynomial) or any other ay which will enable me to fit the equations properly?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: **

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath*}
    r=-\frac{h}{2 a}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}
    {3 \sqrt[3]{2} a^2}+\frac{h^2}{a^2}-\frac{2 \left(h^2-1\right)}{3 a^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(h^4-2 h^2-12 a u h-12 a^2 Q^2+1\right)}{3 a^2 \sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a^2}+\frac{2 h^2}{a^2}-\frac{4 \left(h^2-1\right)}{3 a^2}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(h^4-2 h^2-12 a u h-12 a^2 Q^2+1\right)}{3 a^2 \sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}-\frac{-\frac{8 h^3}{a^3}+\frac{8 \left(h^2-1\right) h}{a^3}-\frac{16 u}{a^2}}{4 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a^2}+\frac{h^2}{a^2}-\frac{2 \left(h^2-1\right)}{3 a^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(h^4-2 h^2-12 a u h-12 a^2 Q^2+1\right)}{3 a^2 \sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}}}}\\
    \end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. You will have better odds to get an answer if you provide code in a minimal example. You cannot expect that anyone here should try and guess how your expression look. (Apart from that I do not see a point in presenting a big formula like that, but maybe that is a discussion between you and your Master Thesis supervisor.)

Comment: note that red 7 in your screenshot, if you have _any_ error the it is not worth looking at the generated output, exccpt possibly as a debugging aid. You should fix hose first if you want to ask here about an error show the exact error copied from the log file.

Comment: @mickep I am just curious as to how one should format these kind of equations here. Saying that, I shall edit the question with the snippet of the code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The errors are from other chapters mainly and they are "orange' errors except one from this chapter that states $\texttt{'White space in argument : \@input{NRO : CASE.aux}}'$

Comment: This is exactly what I have written to obtain this output. Sorry for using the word snippet.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I modified the question again!

Comment: A good start would be to get rid of all 61[!] instances of `\left` and `\right`, as they do absolutely nothing useful here.

Comment: Ok, I mean can try that, No harm doing it.

Comment: it doesn't matter where the error is, it is showing 7 errors (not warnings) and if there is an error anywhere then any pdf is just more or less accidental debugging information from tex trying to recover, it is not  intended to be usable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only reasonable chance you have to render this super-complicated equation in a way that's legible and parsable is to use additional variable names -- say, `U`, `V`, `W`, etc. (you're of course free to come up with more mnemonic names...) -- to capture terms that occur repeatedly. Say,

[image]

(I would definitely also recommend that you double-check whether I did the substitutions correctly...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Put
\begin{align*}
U &= 2 (h^2-1)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 (h^2-1)-36 a h u (h^2-1)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\\
V & = -4 \bigl((h^2-1)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\bigr)^3\\
W &= \frac{h^2}{a^2}-\frac{2 (h^2-1)}{3 a^2}\\
X &= \sqrt[3]{U+\sqrt{U^2V}}\\
Y &= \sqrt[3]{2} (h^4-2 h^2-12 a u h-12 a^2 Q^2+1)\\
Z &= \sqrt{\frac{X}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a^2}+W+\frac{Y}{3 a^2 X}}\\
\shortintertext{and}
T &= \frac{8 h^3}{a^3}-\frac{8 (h^2-1) h}{a^3}+\frac{16 u}{a^2} \,.
\end{align*}
Then
\[
r=-\frac{h}{2 a}-\frac{1}{2} Z-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-Z^2+3W+T/(4Z)} \,.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: "you can probably define more variables for more sub terms so that the structure is more reasonable" :-) +1 (this is certainly what the OP should do for a hand written document)

Comment: Thank you for the simplifying answer. I understand what you're trying to convey but my question was more related to whether TeX can format it automatically (the equation) w/o me making any changes and from your text I understand that it is simply not the case here.

Comment: @mnuizhre - The main type-setting related issue raised by your equation is that it contains several superlong square and cube root terms. Unfortunately, there is no mechanism in TeX that will allow it to line-break the superlong `\sqrt{...}` and `\sqrt[3]{...}` expressions automatically.

Comment: I see. I understood the issue here. Thanks a lot for guiding!

Answer (score 6):

No one is going to be able to read this so trying to make it look nice seems a lost cause. I defined one simple variable here to reduce the size rather a lot, with more domain knowledge you can probably define more variables for more sub terms so that the structure is more reasonable but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{raggedright}
\renewcommand\frac[2]{(#1)/(#2)}
\renewcommand\sqrt[2][2]{(#2)^{1/#1}}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}\selectfont

$g=h^2-1$

$\displaystyle r=-\frac{h}{2 a}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2
      g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a h u g-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{(2
        g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a h u g-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2)^2-4
        (g^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u)^3}}} {3 \sqrt[3]{2}
    a^2}+\frac{h^2}{a^2}-\frac{2 g}{3 a^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} (h^4-2 g2
    a u h-12 a^2 Q^2+1)}{3 a^2 \sqrt[3]{2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a h u
      g-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{(2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a h u
        g-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2)^2-4 (g^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h
        u)^3}}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2
      g-36 a h u g-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{(2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2
        g-36 a h u g-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2)^2-4 (g^2-12 a^2
        Q^2-12 a h u)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a^2}+\frac{2
    h^2}{a^2}-\frac{4 g}{3 a^2}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} (h^4-2 g2 a u h-12
    a^2 Q^2+1)}{3 a^2 \sqrt[3]{2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a h u g-108 a^2
      h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{(2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a h u g-108 a^2
        h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2)^2-4 (g^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h
        u)^3}}}-\frac{-\frac{8 h^3}{a^3}+\frac{8 g h}{a^3}-\frac{16
      u}{a^2}}{4 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a h u
          g-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{(2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a
            h u g-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2)^2-4 (g^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12
            a h u)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a^2}+\frac{h^2}{a^2}-\frac{2
        g}{3 a^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} (h^4-2 g2 a u h-12 a^2 Q^2+1)}{3
        a^2 \sqrt[3]{2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a h u g-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108
          a^2 u^2+\sqrt{(2 g^3+72 a^2 Q^2 g-36 a h u g-108 a^2 h^2
            Q^2+108 a^2 u^2)^2-4 (g^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u)^3}}}}}} $
  
\end{raggedright}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this answer is the closest it comes to answering the question about formatting! +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured that if one wants to see such length of equation on the screen without having to convert the style of the equation etc. (just for the heck of it) then they can make certain changes in the orientation of the page, geometry (margin, borders etc.), font sizes and article type altogether.

For me, I used the [exstizes package](https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extsizes.pdf) to change the font size to even smaller value which none of the standard LaTeX classes support. I am able to see the entire expression on my screen with the help of the following code.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a0paper, landscape, margin=0in}
\begin{document}


\begin{dmath*}
    r=-\frac{h}{2 a}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}
    {3 \sqrt[3]{2} a^2}+\frac{h^2}{a^2}-\frac{2 \left(h^2-1\right)}{3 a^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(h^4-2 h^2-12 a u h-12 a^2 Q^2+1\right)}{3 a^2 \sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a^2}+\frac{2 h^2}{a^2}-\frac{4 \left(h^2-1\right)}{3 a^2}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(h^4-2 h^2-12 a u h-12 a^2 Q^2+1\right)}{3 a^2 \sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}-\frac{-\frac{8 h^3}{a^3}+\frac{8 \left(h^2-1\right) h}{a^3}-\frac{16 u}{a^2}}{4 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a^2}+\frac{h^2}{a^2}-\frac{2 \left(h^2-1\right)}{3 a^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(h^4-2 h^2-12 a u h-12 a^2 Q^2+1\right)}{3 a^2 \sqrt[3]{2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2+\sqrt{\left(2 \left(h^2-1\right)^3+72 a^2 Q^2 \left(h^2-1\right)-36 a h u \left(h^2-1\right)-108 a^2 h^2 Q^2+108 a^2 u^2\right)^2-4 \left(\left(h^2-1\right)^2-12 a^2 Q^2-12 a h u\right)^3}}}}}}\\
    \end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```